# How does one add an image to an existing Stack Overflow problem?

Tags: discussion

Already, on a new post like this one I see these icons above...

The 6th icon is where I can click to add picture.  But what now?  Do I need an imgur.com account?  Is there a way to to used a local file (name.jpg or nam.png) from my hard drive? [image: Got it to drag in drop a Windows file object (i.e., dragged from file explorer.]  And Browse and Paste seems to have problems.

Comment: The joke was on me...... ha!  Look mom, no image.

Comment: The image found there was by a drag-n-drop from file explorer. (The Browse option and the Paste choice did not work)   Okay, couldn't make main post operate in a predictable manner where the editor had icons, So I need help THERE. BUT NOW that we are HERE (Add comment section) those mis-functioning icons are no longer present.  Ctrl-G opens a Chrome find function in the browser.  I understand image capture risks, but then, a **much** better tutorial must be made and then linked off-of the SO "help" Webpage regarding formatting of comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you click **Browse** it opens a file browser where you can find an image on your local drive. If you click **Paste** it shows a field where you can paste a URL to an image, or if you have an image in your clipboard, just the image itself.

These work for me in Chrome Version 78.0.3904.97 (Official Build) (64-bit), Microsoft Edge Version 80.0.320.5 (Official build) dev (64-bit) [Chromium-based], Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0, and Firefox 70.0.1 (64-bit), all on Windows 10.

You've never been able to put images in comments. Comments are for clarification of questions or answers, you shouldn't need to put images in them. If you must, you can put links to images by drafting an answer, using the image tool to add the image, then copying and pasting the image URL produced into the comment and discarding the answer.